# Why won't mon-put-data accept multiple values?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I downloaded the command-line tools, CloudWatch-2010-08-01.zip (the latest version, as far as I know). According to [the on-line documentation,](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/cli-mon-put-data.html) I should be able to send multiple statistics in one go:

```
-m, --metric-name VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3...
The name of the Metric to be gathered. Required.
```

But my copy of mon-put-data tells me that I can only send one at a time - this is from the usage information that it prints out:

```
-m, --metric-name VALUE
   The name of the Metric to be gathered. Required.
```

Did I mess something up, or did Amazon get their versions mixed up?

Answer (score 0):

It's one at a time, because that's what the web service API supports.

The most recent version of the CLI tools is actually the [AWS Unified CLI Tools](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli). It maps 1:1 with the web service API, so it should be clearer how to use it. The autocomplete is handy as well.

If you also install the recommended [jq](http://stedolan.github.com/jq/) CLI tool, you can do something like this:

```
prompt > aws cloudwatch list-metrics | jq ".Metrics[].MetricName" | sort | uniq
"CPUUtilization"
"DatabaseConnections"
"DiskQueueDepth"
"DiskReadBytes"
"DiskReadOps"
"DiskWriteBytes"
"DiskWriteOps"
"FreeStorageSpace"
"FreeableMemory"
"HTTPCode_Backend_2XX"
"HTTPCode_Backend_3XX"
"HTTPCode_Backend_4XX"
"HTTPCode_Backend_5XX"
"HealthyHostCount"
"Latency"
"NetworkIn"
"NetworkOut"
"NumberOfMessagesPublished"
"NumberOfNotificationsDelivered"
"NumberOfNotificationsFailed"
"ProvisionedReadCapacityUnits"
"ProvisionedWriteCapacityUnits"
"PublishSize"
"ReadIOPS"
"ReadLatency"
"ReadThroughput"
"RequestCount"
"StatusCheckFailed"
"StatusCheckFailed_Instance"
"StatusCheckFailed_System"
"SwapUsage"
"UnHealthyHostCount"
"VolumeIdleTime"
"VolumeQueueLength"
"VolumeReadBytes"
"VolumeReadOps"
"VolumeTotalReadTime"
"VolumeTotalWriteTime"
"VolumeWriteBytes"
"VolumeWriteOps"
"WriteIOPS"
"WriteLatency"
"WriteThroughput"

prompt >
```

From there, you can check out the API reference for [GetMetricStatistics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricStatistics.html) and put together this query:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics \
    --metric-name CPUUtilization \
    --statistics Average \
    --namespace AWS \
    --period 600 \
    --start-time 20130320 \
    --end-time 20130323
```

Comment: First: you're wrong about the web API. It does accept multiple metrics at a time, you can see an example here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricData.html

Comment: Second: I was asking specifically about the Cloudwatch tools. I already have a lot of scripts that depend on them, so I'm not gonna switch to a completely new toolkit unless there's a very good reason. I just wanted to know why the on-line docs don't match what I have.

Comment: Ah, forgive me. I thought you were trying to GET instead of PUT. Yes, you can do multiple PUTs in a single call.

Comment: You had said "the latest version, as far as I know". I was letting you know that, no, they're not the latest version. If you're using the legacy CloudWatch tools and can't/won't upgrade, then I'm not sure. I'm not sure what the support status of those tools is, but you could probably as the CloudWatch team directly on the [AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=138).